# ¿Cómo podría personalizar las viñetas en wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Quisiera saber como podría personalizar el "punto" que aparece como viñeta en el wordpress por un guion "-". Ya que al colocar el guion dentro del párrafo, no obtengo el formato de alineación deseada.

¿Existe algún plugin para las viñetas?

Answer (score 3):

Primero debes agregar la imagen a mostrar en el subdirectorio images de la plantilla usada.

Seguno debes aregar el siguiente formato al archivo "style.css" de la plantilla usada.

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url(images/iagen_a_mostrar.png);
}
```

Si solo quieres cambiarla sin imagen puede ser:

```
ul{ list-style-type:square;}

ul{ list-style-type:circle;}
```